# How to prevent Visual Studio 2008 from checking references in .aspx files?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

There was a registry fix for Visual Studio 2005 to prevent it from checking references in .aspx files, but it does not seem to work for 2008. With variable renames, finding all references in an ASP.NET project is extremely slow. Is there a way to prevent this in VS2008?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one thing I have given up hope for ever working right in Visual Studio. This is also one of the primary reasons I started using ReSharper in the first place.

Other than some 3rd party plugin, I have no other suggestions for you.